# Google Cloud Messaging often return "NotRegistered" error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I try to make a chat with a client (app Android) and a server (J2EE). 
The purpose of my app is to make a chat with anybody.

There are three activies: The first is a splashScreen with GCM resister in background, when register is done, I start the second activity.

The second activity allow the user to choose his login and wait for an user. When a user come, this activity receive a push notification and start the last activity.

The third activity is the chat, an user can send message and receive message. When an user send a message, the server send push notification to force data synchronization from the other one.

Here's my problem, my client lost his registration after one or two push notification. But sometimes it works for more than 10... I don't understand why I have this trouble. I found on stackoverflow explication of NotRegistered error but there are severals reasons...

So, I have three questions:

1. Can I get from google GCM log for my application to understand what is the problem?
2. Is there a way to detect this error on the client side?
3. Somebody know why I have this problem?

Here's my code:

**Manifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.test.app.activity.SplashScreenActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.app.activity.NicknameActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.app.activity.ConversationActivity">
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**GCMHelper:**

```
public class GCMHelper {

    public final static String SENDER_ID = "MY ID";

    public static void register(final Context context, final Activity activity) {
        new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                try {
                    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    gcm.register(GCM.SENDER_ID);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                super.onPostExecute(o);
                // Start NicknameActivity
            }
        }.execute(null,null,null);
    }

}
```

**SplashScreenActivity:**

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
        GCMHelper.register(getApplicationContext(), this);
    }

    }
```

**NicknameActivity:**

```
public class NicknameActivity extends Activity {

private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
private BroadcastReceiver gcmBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // start conversation activity
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(gcmBroadcastReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(gcmBroadcastReceiver);
}

}
```

**ConversationActivity**:

```
public class ConversationActivity extends Activity {

private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
private BroadcastReceiver gcmBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // HTTP request to get the message
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(gcmBroadcastReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(gcmBroadcastReceiver);
}
}
```

PS: Sorry for my english, if you have any trouble for read my text. Ask me ;)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Prior to the `NotRegistered` error, are you receiving all the messages sent to your Android app? I suspect that it is a false assumption by the GCM server that your app has been uninstalled. This could be the case if your broadcast receiver has not been configured correctly to listen to these broadcast messages. Refer to item 4 onward [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg-how).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I get all messages before NotRegistered error. I think you're right. I guess because I use BroadcastReceiver (with register in my activity) I can miss one message from GCM, so I'm disconnect. May be if I use a service I will always manage message and I won't have that error... But that mean a lot of changes... So if you or anybody know a solution with broadcastReceiver that work please give me a hand:)